# Best practice for updating dependent state across different branches of the state tree?

Tags: redux

I have this state:

- users: [{money: 1}]
- products: [{id: 'x', price: 5}, {id: 'y', price: 1}]
- purchasedProducts: []

I want to add an action `{type: "buyProduct", productId: "x"}`, which will add a new product and subtract money from the user. But I have 3 different reducers for each branch (users/products/purchasedProducts).

let's say now I add a new product "x", which costs 5, it should not remove money and it should not add the product as well. Note that the 5 comes from the products branch. So the users and purchasedProducts can't figure out the price from the action itself as it only contains the id and not the price.

My real example is a bit more complicated but similar in nature.

Solutions:

- A) One solution is to have a root reducer for all branches, but doesn't feel right. Any other solutions?
- B) Have another action "requestPurchase" and this will calcultae if I can buy the product or not. The problem with this is that might have some concurrency problems if there are 2 requestPurchase at the same time as it will allow both actions to pass even if not enough money.

Comment: assuming you have money on user basis, you can call multiple dispatch actions, first check if user can buy the product then add to cart and reduce the money, this will be 3 dispatch but it is okay to have.

Comment: "first check if user can buy": Yes, that's basically the solution B, but has a problem when involves concurrency. If I have 2 actions at the same time it will break because it will process the 2 actions first and only then it will commit to the state. I'm using rxjs so it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/655

Comment: @Justcode Thank you, but doesn't help for this scenario. My state is normalized and the actions can be concurrent because I'm using some indirection after the action is dispatched with rxjs.